# Изменение границ отрисовки на PictureBox при увеличении окна приложения

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

При отрисовке инициализировал картинку , на которой рисую через
    `visibleclipbounds    img = new Bitmap( (int ) g.VisibleClipBounds.Width, (int)g.VisibleClipBounds.Height);`
При увеличение окна возможность рисовать остается только в начальном месте , где изначально открылось окно . Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Расширьте размер самого элемента управления `PictureBox`. То есть присвойте его свойству `Size` новое значение.

```
PictureBox0.Size = this.Size
```

Эту строку поместите в обработчик события формы `Resize`. Тогда `PictureBox0` будет соответствовать размеру формы (игнорируя бордюры и размер заголовка; подробнее в `SystemInformation`)